# Photo captured from Ipad will be inverted at server

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

I am developing an application in phonegap and have functionality of photo capturing using Ipad camera, It works fina and all photo saved properly on server. the only issue was with the fact that they are rotated 90 degree left while saved on server.

Now i tried same thing for photos stored in library and they are upload as it is on server, so i think issue is with ipad photo capturing process. Can anyone help me to found solution for such problem. Is it Ipad normal behaviour or i have mistaken in code ?

I have used below function for photo functionality

```
//Capture Photo either from camera or IPAD library
   function capturePhoto(source){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //When source == 1 than from Photo Library
    var cameraOptions = { quality: 70, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI };
    if(source == 1){ cameraOptions = { quality: 70, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,targetWidth: 600,targetHeight: 600 }; }

    navigator.camera.getPicture( function (imageURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function (fileEntry) {

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {

                  fileSys.root.getDirectory("auditPhotos", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir) {

                      fileEntry.copyTo(dir,generateRandomID()+".jpg",function (entry) {
                                       deferred.resolve(entry.fullPath)
                      }, null);
                  }, null);
            }, null);
        },null);
      },
      function (message)  {
        deferred.reject(message);
      },
      cameraOptions
    );
    //deferred.resolve(generateRandomID()+".jpg");
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are saving captured image (Using above function) on server in jpg format. JPG  & JPEG's have a property of EXIF which store orientation of image. When you captured image through IPAD, this exif data stores camera orientation and other position related things. But this are understood by ipad only and not by browser, that's why image was seen rotated in browser which is the truth. And same image when you viewed in IPAD it was set by IPAD in proper position due to availablity of EXIF.

To solve this problem just save your image in PNG format instead of JPG and all works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a similar problem recently, and while I'm not too sure how to specifically solve your problem, I do know that EXIF data on the image should store something about how it's oriented.

You can try implementing this library to get the EXIF data and rotate the image if needed before the upload: https://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/